# how to process tcp_check for golang tcp proxy

Tags: go, tcp, proxy

I write a tcp proxy with golang, for smtp and other protocols.

code like this:

```
ln,_:=net.Listen("tcp",":xx")
conn,_:=ln.Accept()
remoteConn,_:=net.Dial("tcp","xxx:xx")
go io.Copy(remoteConn,conn)
go io.Copy(conn,remoteConn)
```

**It work fine, forward smtp message success.**

**a new question**
When I deploy the proxy backend of LVS, the LVS send TCP_CHECK to proxy every second, When the proxy receives the request, it immediately establishes a connection to the remote server, but nothing data to write to.

Many nothing tcp connection to remote email server, it's very bad.

**I tried :**
Read all request data at first, if reqeust is TCP_CHECK, read will error(lvs send nothing to my proxy), then I know it's a TCP_CHECK request, it will not forward to remote email server.
**But this is not work for smtp, Because the SMTP protocol interacts multiple times**
Something about smtp: https://www.smtp2go.com/blog/understanding-smtp-protocol/

Ask for help, any idea about how to process LVS's TCP_CHECK with golang?

Comment: Given that in SMTP the server is expected to send data first it is impossible to distinguish based on client data if this is a real client or just a check. You might use `bindto` to configure a specific IP address used as source for the check and make sure that no real client uses this source IP. Then you can check in your code where the connections comes from to detect if it is a check or not. Another option would be to additionally listen on a different port just for the tcp check.